# Why operation_Id is empty in appinsight for some columns

Tags: azure-application-insights

i am trying to excute some query

```
let firstString="error code :";
let secondString="|";

let apiResultCode = "400";
requests
| where resultCode has apiResultCode
| join ( traces 
| where message has firstString
| extend ErrorCode = substring(message, (indexof(message,firstString, 0))+ string_size(firstString),
-1*(((indexof(message,firstString, 0))+ string_size(firstString))-indexof(message,secondString,(toint(indexof(message,firstString, 0) + string_size(firstString)))))
 ))on operation_Id
 | project timestamp,url,ErrorCode,name,resultCode
```

but i am not getting proper result because of blank field of operation_id, i just want to know why operation id is blank for some fields and also is there any other fields through which we can corelate the queries?